# Getting parameter from React-Native Application using JSP file as the controller

Tags: java, jsp, react-native, fetch

I am learning react-native and suddenly happen to meet a problem. The development structure of my work is where the react-native as my front end and the JSP as my backend. When I try to request or get the parameter that I send using the fetch function, I can get it. Can anyone help me? Below is the Code that I write for the fetch:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName : '',
      userPass : ''
    }

  }


  login = () => {

      const {userName} = this.state;
      const {userPass} = this.state;

      if(userName == '' || userPass == '') {

        Alert.alert('Warning' , 'Please Insert All the Required Details !!!!');

      } else {


        fetch('newjsp1.jsp', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: userName,
            pass: userPass
          }),
        })        
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
        });


      }

  }



  render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <ImageBackground source={require('../img/1.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
                <View style={styles.content}>

                    <Text style={styles.logo}> -- LOGIN DEMO -- </Text>

                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.input} placeholder='USERNAME' onChangeText = {userName => this.setState({userName})} >
                        </TextInput>
                        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent' secureTextEntry={true} style={styles.input} placeholder='PASSWORD' onChangeText = {userPass => this.setState({userPass})} >
                        </TextInput> 
                    </View>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            </ImageBackground>

        </View>
    );

  }


}
```

Below is the receiving JSP file:

```
<%

    String user = request.getParameter("name");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("USERNAME", user);
    obj.put("PASSWORD", pass);


    out.print(obj);


%>
```

I cant get the data that I send when I use `request.getParameter()`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @bennygenel Sorry for the that friend. I am new to stackoverflow. That is my post is like that.

Comment: @Suraj Rao Thanks for the edit friend

Comment: Don't worry about it. You fixed it. It is the important part and Welcome to SO. For your question, I don't know anything about JSP but I'm guessing that the problem is caused by you are sending your parameters as body of the request and trying to read them from params. parameters usually referred to query strings so this might be the issue but I'm sure someone better with JSP can give a better answer

Comment: I think JSP have no out of the box support for request with `Content-Type:application/json`. You can check `request.getReader()` have the request body. PS: Use `JAX-RS` if possible for this use case. `jsp` are meant for rendering view.